# RxJs with Jest case fails but the `tap` output shows correctly

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

Following test case, will return the data correctly but JEST show as failed. The test is written using `TestScheduler`

Jest Result

```
    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected
    + Received

    - Array [
    -   Object {
    -     "frame": 3,
    -     "notification": Notification {
    -       "error": undefined,
    -       "hasValue": true,
    -       "kind": "N",
    -       "value": Object {
    -         "type": "INITIALIZED",
    -       },
    -     },
    -   },
    - ]
    + Array []
```

Code

```
    
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';
import { mergeMap, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing';


describe('routechange epic', () => {

    const testScheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
        expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });

    it('check apollo', () => {
        const dependencies = {
            apolloClient: {
                mutate: ({ mutation, variables }: { mutation: any, variables: any }) =>
                    Promise.resolve({
                        data: { param: 'testA' }
                    })
            },
        };
        const initializeOrg = (action$, state$, { apolloClient }) =>
            action$
                .pipe(
                    ofType('START'),
                    tap(act => console.log('---AAA', act)),
                    mergeMap(action =>
                        from(
                            apolloClient.mutate({
                                mutation: `something`,
                                variables: {
                                    orgId: (action as any).params || ''
                                }
                            })
                        )
                            .pipe(
                                tap(x => console.log('----x', x)),
                                map(response => ({
                                    type: 'INITIALIZED',
                                    response,
                                }))
                            )
                    )
                );



        testScheduler.run(({ hot, cold, expectObservable }) => {
            const action$ = hot('-a', {
                a: { type: 'START', params: 'SomethingA' }
            });
            const state$ = null;

            const output$ = initializeOrg(action$, state$, dependencies);

            expectObservable(output$).toBe('---a', {
                a: {
                    type: 'INITIALIZED'
                }
            })
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Could you reproduce the error in a StackBlitz app? You could start [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9mhssk?file=src/app/auth-guard.service.spec.ts).

Comment: `Promise.resolve` resolves asynchronously and the `TestScheduler` does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use `Promise.resolve` as someone commented it.

It worked now with cold observable like below.

```
import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';
import { mergeMap, map, tap, toArray, take } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing';


describe('routechange epic', () => {



    it('check apollo', async () => {
        const testScheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
            expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
        });


        const initializeOrg = (action$, state$, { apolloClient }) =>
            action$
                .pipe(
                    ofType('START'),
                    tap(act => console.log('---AAA', act)),
                    mergeMap(action =>
                        from(
                            apolloClient.mutate({
                                mutation: `something`,
                                variables: {
                                    orgId: (action as any).params || ''
                                }
                            })
                        )
                            .pipe(
                                tap(x => console.log('----x', x)),
                                map(response => ({
                                    type: 'INITIALIZED',
                                    response,
                                }))
                            )
                    )
                );



        testScheduler.run(({ hot, cold, expectObservable }) => {
            const action$ = hot('-a', {
                a: { type: 'START', params: 'SomethingA' }
            });
            const state$ = null;
            const dependencies = {
                apolloClient: {
                    mutate: ({ mutation, variables }: { mutation: any, variables: any }) =>
                        cold('--a|', {
                            a: { data: { param: 'testA' } }
                        })
                },
            };
            const output$ = initializeOrg(action$, state$, dependencies);

            expectObservable(output$).toBe('---a', {
                a: {
                    type: 'INITIALIZED',
                    response: {
                        data: { param: 'testA' }
                    }
                }
            })
        });

    });
});
```